# Twitter typeahead match from start of sentence

Tags: javascript

I am using Twitter typeahead,  I need help to implement the following:

User types "move" and the data set list is as follows(Is move to, move over, was move, move to)

I want to return only 2nd and 4th items from the list ie only match from the beginning only.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what errors are you getting? Please share some code

Comment: var optionSuburbIDs = $('#optionSuburbIDs option')
        .map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        })
        .get();

        var engineSuburb = new Bloodhound({
            name: 'optionSuburbIDs',
            datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val); },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: $.map(optionSuburbIDs, function(optionSuburb) { return { val: optionSuburb }; })
        });
        engineSuburb.initialize();

Comment: When I type "move", all items get return since all of them contain the word "move",  I want to return only items that start with word "move"